# Possible to write an Express GET route that accepts an array of unknown length?

Tags: express

Like the title says, is it possible to write an Express GET route that accepts an array of unknown length?

I know I can use a POST request and just include an array in the body, but it isn't posting something so much as getting something!

I need to know how to encode the url. Most of what I am seeing is for arrays of particular length. This could be for 2 or 20, or more.

Comment: You should be able to encode an array to the URL and read it back with `req.params`

Comment: Can you give a little direction on encoding the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YES!

You can use the query parameter and use a delimiter, as search engines of old where your search string was actually in the url with spaces demarcated with +. This allows for an array of indeterminate length.

Did not get any feedback for HOW to encode an array to accept a url, so this is the approach I am going with. Even in my googling I couldn't find much on HOW to encode a URL to have an array in the params object, rather than the query object, possibly because I was searching for how to do it for an array of indeterminate length?